# Implicit Type Conversions in Reflection

Tags: c#, casting

So I've written a quick bit of code to help quickly convert between business objects and view models. Not to pimp my own blog, but [you can find the details here](http://bradhe.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/from-business-objects-to-data-contracts-and-back-again/) if you're interested or need to know.

One issue I've run in to is that I have a custom collection type, ProductCollection, and I need to turn that in to a string[] in on my model. Obviously, since there is no default implicit cast, I'm getting an exception in my contract converter.

So, I thought I would write the next little bit of code and that should solve the problem:

```
public static implicit operator string[](ProductCollection collection) {
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (var product in collection)
    {
        if (product.Id == null)
        {
            list.Add(null);
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(product.Id.ToString());
        }
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

However, it still fails with the same cast exception. I'm wondering if it has something to do with being in reflection? If so, is there anything that I can do here?? I'm open to architectural solutions, too!

Comment: What intrinsic value do you hope to gain from adding the null strings to the list you're generating? Just wondering.

Comment: You said `cast exception` but declared an `implicit` operator.  Did you mean to declare an `explicit` operator?  Post the code where you're expecting this to get triggered.

Comment: Nathan Taylor, if product.Id was null, a ToString() on it would end the universe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `implicit` operator allows for *implcit* conversions (no casting directive). `explicit` operators operate on casts.

Nonetheless, that isn't the real issue here. Operators are not polymorphic (they're *overloaded*, not *overridden*); that is, in order to take advantage of an overloaded operator, you must be referring to a class in the context of the class that defines it.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static implicit operator Bar(Foo foo) { return new Bar(); }
}

public class Bar { }

...

void Baz()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    Bar bar = foo; // OK

    object baz = foo;

    bar = baz; // won't compile, there's no defined operator at the object level

    bar = (Bar)baz; // will compile, but will fail at runtime for the same reason
}
```

Without knowing what you're doing and how you're doing it, I can't offer much in the way of a meaningful alternative. Some ideas, however:

1. Override `ToString` (or use a common base class / interface for your entities with your own version if you don't want to use `ToString`) on your entities, then enumerate the collections generically to construct your string array
2. Provide a `ToStringArray` function on your collections (by way of a common base class or interface) that does something similar

The biggest point is *not* to use operators for this purpose; they won't help you.

Comment: This is a very excellent explanation. Thanks! 

This is an obscure bit of the language that I was unaware of until looking for a solution for this.